# Почему может быть ошибка в postman 400 Bad Request при отправке запроса?

Tags: postman

Я отправляю запрос через json raw:

```
{
    "age": 20,
    "salary": 5000,
    "name": "Anna",
    "auth_token":{{token}}
}
```

Приходит такая ошибка:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Точно проблема не в токене и в не url. тогда что не так? Json правильно написан

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где кавычки вокруг токена?

Comment: Точно!!!Блин спасибо!)